# Self join table where results list the same column twice with different results

Tags: mysql, self-join

**edit:**

I have a db table with two columns: id and dep, that lists all department names.

is it possible to run a query (either self join or subquery) that returns the dep column twice (dep1 and dep2).

dep1 would like all departments.

dep2 would list only departments that contain an &

I hoped this would be possible but have yet to find/test a query that works.

Am I out to lunch on this?

**original post:**

My need is to create a query to return the same column twice--the first column showing all results and the second column showing only names with special characters (& and ').

I have two queries, below, that I would like to turn into a self join.

```
SELECT dep
FROM `test_deps`
where dep like "%&%" or dep like "%'%"
```

Returns:

```
dep (col name)
CAPS - Dean's Office
Parking & Transportation


SELECT dep
FROM `test_deps`
where dep not like "%&%" or dep not like "%'%"
```

Returns:

```
dep (col name)
Admissons
```

I a query that returns:

```
dep1                            dep2
Admissions
CAPS - Dean's Office            CAPS - Dean's Office
Parking & Transportation        Parking & Transportation
```

I tried this query that obviously does not work.

```
SELECT h1.dep as dep1, h2.dep as dep2
FROM test_deps h1
INNER JOIN test_deps h2
ON h1.id=h2.id
WHERE h1.dep like "%&%"
or h1.dep like "%'%"
or h2.dep not like "%&%"
AND h2.dep not like "%'%"
```

Maybe I need to turn `h2.dep as dep` in the select into a query.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please indent code reasonably per syntax & semantics.

Comment: Clearly your error(s) & goal will be faqs Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: "turn into a self join" etc & 2 fragments & 1 example do not constitute a clear description of how the desired result is a function of inputs. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Do you understand AND has higher precedence than OR?

Comment: Your last edit undid my edit before it. Please when you edit reload the page for the current version of a post & also heed any warnings that another edit has happened. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. [When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/266284) PS Adding to something unclear does not make it clear. Organize a clear presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional expressions.

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN dep like "%&%" or dep like "%'%"
            THEN dep 
            END dep1,
       CASE WHEN dep not like "%&%" or dep not like "%'%"
            THEN dep 
            END dep2
FROM `test_deps`
-- HAVING dep1 IS NOT NULL AND dep2 IS NOT NULL
;
```

If you do not need in the rows which does not match both conditions (for example, `dep = NULL`) then uncomment HAVING clause.

If you need in empty string instead of NULLs in the output then add `ELSE ''` to both CASEs (and edit HAVING conditions accordingly).